# Setting up Samba really that easy?

Tags: security, samba, setup

I set up an ubuntu-server and installed Samba. I set the "interfaces" option in the .conf-file to "lo eth0".

My question is according to the security of this system:
Am I done with the setup process? Do I need additional things to make my system safe?

Most of the Samba-How-To's stop at this point.
I only want to access the fileserver from LAN. It is behind a "Fritzbox".

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes, setting up Samba is really that easy. Samba is meant to be uncomplicated to setup, so there's not much you have to do.